# cannot find symbol : class java.awt.graphics

Tags: java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class string3 extends Applet implements TextListener{
Label lblMessage;
TextField txtText1;
String strString1="";
public void init(){
lblMessage=new Label("enter some words");
add(lblMessage);
txtText1.addTextListener(this);
}
public void paint(Graphics objG){
objG.drawString="strString 1,202,42";
}
public void textValueChanged(TextEvent objE){
strString1=txtText1.getText();
repaint();
}
}
```

the cmd says

C:\sample java>javac string3.java
string3.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable drawString
location: class java.awt.Graphics
objG.drawString="strString 1,202,42";

1 error

Comment: You should not start doing GUI programming, which is hard, if you don't know the difference between an attribute and a method, and don't know how to find and read javadoc. Read an introductory Java, or even programming book, and practice with simple, console-based exercises. Also learn to indent your code, respect Java naming conventions, and choose good names for your variables. `strString1` and `txtText1` are really awful names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drawString` is a method and not a variable. So you need to pass the parameters to method instead of assigning them. You need to change this:

```
objG.drawString="strString 1,202,42";
```

to:

```
objG.drawString(strString1,202,42);
```

Comment: it has the same error

Comment: @Junel I have corrected the answer a bit, try that.

Comment: i tried it,,but have the same error

Comment: @Junel can u share your updated code.

Comment: @Junel you are not using what i recommended: replace this objG.drawString("strString 1,202,42"); with objG.drawString(strString1,202,42);

Comment: it's ok..thank you very much @Juned Ahsan